# How to apply rule on Total cost in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to apply 20% off on total cost of Rs 3000 without any coupon.I have done this in shopping cart rule because I did not get the option of Subtotal in catalog price rule.

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with Catalog Price rules. Instead, use a Shopping Cart price rule:

**Rule Information:**

[image]

**Conditions:**

[image]

**Actions:**

[image]